# Warning passing store as prop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a component who receive the `store` via props. So tslint with the airbnb preset tells me I have to declare `PropTypes` for store, so I added:

```
Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

But `Prop type object is forbidden`. So I changed the code to:

```
Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
};
```

But now the browser console says me:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `store.dispatch` of type `function` supplied to `Root`, expected `object`.
```

In my `index.js` I have:

```
const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root store={store} />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `PropTypes.object.isRequired` is valid. Where did `Prop type object is forbidden` error message triggered from?

Comment: From `airbnb` linter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why airbnb linter does not allow object as a PropType, but you could try the shape syntax from the React docs

```
 // An object taking on a particular shape
  optionalObjectWithShape: React.PropTypes.shape({
    color: React.PropTypes.string,
    fontSize: React.PropTypes.number
  }),
```

you can also disable this rule

https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/forbid-prop-types.md#when-not-to-use

"This rule is a formatting/documenting preference and not following it won't negatively affect the quality of your code. This rule encourages prop types that more specifically document their usage."

Looks like airbnb's code itself had some violations of this rule and they disabled it.